# Sidekiq: how to unquiet

Tags: sidekiq

The sidekiq Gui has a quiet button,
useful when you want the # of active threads to become zero,
and you want to do some maintenance on the database, such as creating an index on a column.
Now I have created the index, now I want sidekiq to continue normal operation,
so how does one tell sidekiq to unquiet itself?

I can do a `heroku ps:restart worker` but that's a bit heavy handed I feel.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot unquiet a process; `ps:restart` is correct.

Comment: No, that is part of Sidekiq's overall design: `booting -> running -> quiet -> shutdown`. Cannot go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following on the worker's pod (machine):

```
sidekiq
```

At first it looked like it errored, but it actually restarted the worker.